# soql query on selfserviceuser

Tags: soql

I wanted to get name of account from selfserviceuser object however getting error, I used below query :

```
Select contactid, contact.account.name from selfserviceuser;
```

Any guess what am I doing wrong and how to correct it ??

Comment: Is that a custom object?

Comment: No, this is not a custom object.

Comment: I am getting error that contact relationship is unknown.

Comment: Where are you trying to execute this query from?

Comment: Workbench, but does that matter ?

Comment: Just thinking whether you might be using different API version and the object is still available. I would check field level security and object permissions too for the current user.

Comment: I am trying on workbench, if I remove contact.account.name the query works fine.

Comment: Check if your user has permission for the account object

Comment: Yes user does have permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't traverse to the contact from a self-service user, so even if you try something like:

```
Select contactid, contact.name from selfserviceuser;
```

that will also fail. I haven't found any documentation stating this, but when looking at the schema explorer for an object where I can traverse the contact relationship, a case for example, I see the following:

[image]

Note the foreign key field that matches the relationship name. However, for a Self Service User I see:

[image]

Which is missing the foreign key.